# How to iterate map and assign value to field in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, list, map

I have list of account Ids in an array and list of accounts in array.

I need to find the account Ids from the account list and want to change the status field.

```
var accId=[]; //holding accIds
var accObjectMap = [];
var accList=component.get("v.listOfacc");
console.log('sa##'+accList);
for(var i=0; i<accList.length; i++) {
    console.log('acceee##'+accList[i].Name);
    var temp = { "key": accList[i].Id, "list": [accList[i]] };
    console.log('temp##'+temp);
    accObjectMap.push(temp);
 }

 for(var j=0;j<accId.length;j++){

     console.log('accId##'+accId[j]);
 }
```

Eg : My accId have 2 account ids .My accList have 6 values. I want to find that 2 values from acclist and assign the status as "New".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.prototype.filter, Array.prototype.indexOf, and Array.prototype.forEach:

```
var accIds = []; // Has account Ids
var accountList = component.get("v.listOfacc");
var accountsToUpdate = accountList.filter(item => accIds.indexOf(item.Id) > -1);
accountsToUpdate.forEach(item => item.Status__c = "New");
```

`filter` accepts a method that returns true/false for each item and returns an Array for each item where the value is true. `indexOf` finds a matching value in an Array or returns -1. `forEach` takes each item in an Array and passes it to a method; we use this to update the status of each account.

Comment: Thanks .The account status got updated. But the list holds only that 2 records .I want to display all the 6 records with the 2 updated value records.

Comment: @jessy It wasn't clear that was what you were trying to do in your original question. You'd want to set the original list back in to your attribute (`component.set("v.listOfacc", accountList);`).

Comment: yes . I am iterating the list "v.listOfacc" in aura :iteration .I have a pick list option for status field. whenever i select value it will apply to account records and display the accounts with updated status.

Comment: @jessy Did you get your problem solved? If not, anything else I can do?

Comment: my problem got resolved .Thanks for you help